# Model for supervised learning on graphs with varying structure

Tags: r, graph, machine-learning, regression, supervised-learning

Colorization problem is considered.

[image: Colorization example]

I have a training set of unordered graphs (images) with varying number of vertices and edges (color regions and adjacency between them, resp.).
[image: Training set of graphs]

A fixed number of features is associated with each vertex (color, area, etc.) and with each edge (length of common border, color contrast, etc.).

For input graph (an image to be colored) the trained model is supposed to specify color for each vertex (color region) of the input graph.

Classic regression algorithms (svm, decision trees, etc.) take fixed sized vectors as input and return fixed sized vectors.

Is there a model that naturally handles varying number of vertices / edges?

Is there an approach to adapt fixed structure models (MRF, factor graphs, etc.) to handle this particular case?

Comment: The first image is from «[Probabilistic Color-by-Numbers: Suggesting Pattern Colorizations Using Factor Graphs](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/patternColoring.html)» where authors present a probabilistic factor graph model for automatically coloring 2D patterns. Unfortunately their approach is limited by fixed size of color palette.

Comment: Probably off-topic here, since it is more about (mathematical) modelling than programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph-based models are proposed in these papers:

- [Gated Graph Sequence Neural Networks](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=258778)
- [Deep Convolutional Networks on Graph-Structured Data](http://gitxiv.com/posts/Lfc2M7chnxG2hsbRQ/deep-convolutional-networks-on-graph-structured-data)
- [The Graph Neural Network Model](http://www.dii.unisi.it/~franco/Research/GNN.php)
- [DeepWalk: Deep Learning for Graphs](http://gitxiv.com/posts/xRKq4MuZyDtS3wR4k/deepwalk-deep-learning-for-graphs)
- [Structural-RNN: Deep Learning on Spatio-Temporal Graphs](http://asheshjain.org/srnn/)